Isolate a subnet for Azure SQL server so it is not publicly accessible
TL;DR - How do I isolate a resource in an Azure subnet so that it is not publicly accessible, but is accessible from other subnets in the same VNET?
Apologies if this isn't the correct site; this is my first foray into networks and both my team and I are struggling despite having hardware experience...
We are trying to set up an Azure network so that users can publicly access web sites hosted using app services, but an Azure SQL Server hosting the back-end databases is not publicly accessible. This is for security to reduce external exposure of the database server.  The app services need to connect to the databases in the subnet.
After studying Azure documentation, using Azure CoPilot and reading various blogs, we've got things set up as follows:

We enabled the option in SQLServerSubnet to "Enable private subnet (no default outbound access)", however any of our team (on different external IP's) can ping the Azure SQL Server using its address, which I didn't expect to be possible:
C:\>ping mySqlServer.database.windows.net 
Pinging cr17.uksouth1-a.control.database.windows.net [51.143.209.226] with 32
  bytes of data: ... Ping statistics for 51.143.209.226:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)

What do I need to do to achieve this please?
I've read that NIC's and NSG's may be used, but I can't find a definitive source of information that answers the question in my context.  We're happy to restructure (e.g. a second VNet) to achieve what we need.

After five days of trial and (mostly) error, we finally found a solution. I feel that as there are three unique setup processes to follow, there is too much information to paste as an answer, so I've included the page titles so an equivalent internet search may also provide answers if the related pages become unavailable.
The finished setup looks like this and involves the processes detailed.  Resources shown in italics are implicitly created as part of the other setup processes, and are shown for clarity.


1. Disable public access to Azure SQL Server & create private endpoint

This initially prevents the Azure SQL Server from being visible to the rest of the subnets, and also from the rest of Azure's services.  The private endpoint setup process implicitly creates the NIC and private DNS Zone and allows the app services to connect to the database.
Ignore any posts saying that disabling public access prevents external SSMS connections; this is dealt with at the end.
Private endpoint overview

2. Create gateway subnet and VPN

This connects your local (external) machine to the VNet and provides it with visibility of the subnets inside the VNet.
Virtual networks > Your VNET > Subnets > +Subnet > Purpose = Virtual Network Gateway

Configure Point to Site VPN Connection using Azure Certificate Authentication

3. Connect from external machine via SSMS


Connect to the VPN via Windows Settings > Networks
Ensure that the server name is the internal subnet IP address, e.g., 10.0.1.5 and not the FQDN.
Important: Ensure the username (if using SQL Authentication) is username@SqlServerFDQN, e.g., admin@mySqlServer.database.windows.net

How to connect to Azure SQL Server using P2S

Please don't forget to eventually accept your answer, so the question doesn't keep popping up forever.

Thanks for the reminder.
